# How to write a method to run automatically only when a conditions comes true

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I want to send a mail to all the customers automatically just 5 days before his licence will get expired.So I have to check the corresponding condition everyday even though I am not running the app, can I actually do it ? if yes suggest me a good way to do this.

Comment: There is actually many ways to achieve what you are asking for. [Azure features](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) and [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) for starters. Please consider your options and ask question with specific problem you have with chosen approach.

Comment: My main issue is that I want to check that condition all the time even when I am not running my application can I actually do it

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26264914/1220550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron task, windows scheduler, windows service, node service, sql job...the list is endless.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the expired date as timestamp in database, and have a cron job running daily to check for customers that license expired in next 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

Create one windows  and  write your code(logic) into it so it will send mail automatically. Run it on your system also integrate that  to your application .

Comment: you mean Windows services ?

Comment: yes windows service in that write your logic and compare user ex.registered with ex. todays date after 5 days count sent an email and run your service on your system 24 hours.