# How to use ef core in a static class with ConcurrentQueues?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

there will be multi request to one action .So I created a static class which has ConcurrentQueue to process the data.

but I can not use `ef core` in it.because it is static class.

and I have to save data and re-read data per request.

otherwise the data will be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static class is 100% out. You can't get it done. However, there's probably no need for an actual static class here. You should instead use a normal class, register it as a singleton, and then inject it where you need it. The context is a scoped service, so you still cannot directly inject it into the class, but you can inject `IServiceProvider` and use the service-locator pattern:

```
using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
// do something with context
```

It's important to note that you can *only* use the context in within the scope of which it's defined. You cannot do something like a set a field or property on the class with it. You'll have to use the above code within each method that needs to use the context within the class.

Comment: @Chirs Pratt Thank you for your answer. it helped me a lot. since I am following https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669109/13258745 can I use the code you gave me in the methods?

Comment: How do you process the mutiple request?

Comment: Based on that, you should *actually* be using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks

Comment: As you say the static class is out. I want to know what is the latest way to deal with multi  request?