# Is it safe not to wait for all tasks

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await

Say I have the following action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostCall()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        tasks.Add(Manager.SomeMethodAsync(i));

    // Is this line necessary to ensure that all tasks will finish successfully?
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    if (tasks.Exists(x => x.Result))
        return new ObjectResult("At least one task returned true");
    else
        return new ObjectResult("No tasks returned true");
}
```

Is `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())` necessary to ensure that all tasks will finish successfully? Will the tasks whose `Result` happened **not** to get accessed by the `Exists` finish their execution in the background successfully? Or is there a chance that some of the tasks (that weren't waited for) get dropped since they would not be attached to the request? Is there a better implementation I'm missing?

Comment: See `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577016/long-running-task-in-webapi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your provided implementation, the `Task.WaitAll` call blocks the calling thread until *all* tasks have completed. It would only proceed to the next line and perform the `Exists` check after this has happened. If you remove the `Task.WaitAll`, then the `Exists` check would cause the calling thread to block on each task in order; i.e. it first blocks on `tasks[0]`; if this returns false, then it would block on `tasks[1]`, then `tasks[2]`, and so on. This is not desirable since it doesn't allow for your method to finish early if the tasks complete out of order.

If you only need to wait until whichever task returns true first, then you could use `Task.WhenAny`. This will make your asynchronous method resume as soon as *any* task completes. You can then check whether it evaluated to true and return success immediately; otherwise, you keep repeating the process for the remaining collection of tasks until there are none left.

If your code was running as an application (WPF, WinForms, Console), then the remaining tasks would continue running on the thread pool until completion, unless the application is shut down. Thread-pool threads are background threads, so they won't keep the process alive if all foreground threads have terminated (e.g. because all windows were closed).

Since you're running a web app, you incur the risk of having your app pool recycled before the tasks have completed. The unawaited tasks are fire-and-forget and therefore untracked by the runtime. To prevent this from happening, you can register them with the runtime through the [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem) method, as suggested in the comments.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostCall()
{
    var tasks = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Select(Manager.SomeMethodAsync)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ => task);

    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        var readyTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(readyTask);
        if (await readyTask)
            return new ObjectResult("At least one task returned true");
    }

    return new ObjectResult("No tasks returned true");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the tasks are not guaranteed to complete unless something waits for them (with something like an await)

In your case, the main change you should make is making the `Task.WaitAll`

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

So it is actually asynchronous. If you just want to wait for *a* task to return, use `WhenAny` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, there is `await` in the implementation of `Manager.SomeMethodAsync`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Using await doesn't *start* the task. The task starts when you call `SomeMethodAsync` etc. There's just no guarantee it will have *completed*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I swear I've had some not even start, but I could have interpreted those wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: If you see that happen again, it'd be great to see a new question about it - then feel free to drop me an email to bring it to my attention. But fundamentally `await` is about consuming a task (or other asynchronous operation) rather than changing the behavior of the task itself.

Comment: And awaiting or not a task has no effect in it completing or not.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Are you saying that `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` will not ensure the completion of all tasks? How is that?

Comment: Kind of. the next line of code will only be executed after all task have been completed. But not awaiting them does not mean that they don't complete.

Comment: @yazanpro: It's technically possible for a method to return an unstarted task (e.g. a `Task` created through its constructor), but that goes against today's conventions: "If a TAP method internally uses a task’s constructor to instantiate the task to be returned, the TAP method must call Start on the Task object before returning it. Consumers of a TAP method may safely assume that the returned task is active and should not try to call Start on any Task that is returned from a TAP method."