# Long running Web API task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, polling

I am trying to find the appropriate way to setup a long running api task using Asp.Net Web API. The tasks I am running could take up to 3 minutes to complete. I have found several links such as [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/) or this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577016/long-running-task-in-webapi) but am unsure on a few things.

**Question:**

So I guess I am most confused about the overall structure for this and the appropriate way to even go about it. My task seems to long to use a QueueBackgroundWorkItem but I don't want to implement a fire and forget API call.

**What I would like:**

I would like to be able to fire a web API task, return a OK response, but continue to poll for the returned data after firing the task. I just have no idea how to even begin implementing a queue system or even how to poll for that data from the Web API.

**Other Information:**

- Using .Net Framework 4.5.2
- Front end is asp.net MVC web app
- Web API method is called through an AJAX call on my front
- Currently send about 30 requests at a time with a long time out. Then as they return I update my UI with returned data from the API.

**My current code:**

This is what I am doing now which works fine. The only issue is I have to set the timeout to some ridiculous amount on my UI application. Which is why I am trying to find the correct way to implement a long running task/polling/queueing mechanism for long running tasks. Overall just unsure what is out there for solving the problem below.

```
public NewProjectLogDTO CreateProject(string modelNumber, string orderName = "")
    {
        try
        {
            string EplanPort = ConnectToEPLAN();
            SetContext(modelNumber, orderName);
            AddSchematicToDB(modelNumber, orderName); //accesses DB
            ExecuteCreateProjectAction(); //Really long running task about 3 minutes long
            DecreasePortCounter(EplanPort);
            AddMacrosToDb(modelNumber, orderName); //accesses DB
            return GetNewProjectLogFromContext(modelNumber,orderName); //return data from long running task
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to offload the work to an external process. There are tools available for you to use. Check out [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). You could use [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) to return an update when there is one back to the client. Do not try to have the web process execute the long running task, web requests should be short lived.

Comment: Yeah I was actually thinking of using SignalR for the communication aspect. Hangfire looks interesting. Is the Pro version worth the cost? Not sure if I really need batching capability. Could you point me to some articles on how to use SignalR with a web api and MVC? Was having trouble finding any good articles over it.

Comment: Sorry, my helpfulness stops after the comment above. I can't tell you about what version to get or point you to material for implementing SignalR outside of the link I had already shared.

Comment: You do not need to pay for Hangfire. There are plenty of ways to code up your own automated task, such as a Windows Serice. One easy and free solution is to use TopShelf which makes it super easy to turn a basic console app into a constantly running Windows Service. http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Currently what we do is use console apps for constantly running / scheduled tasks. How could I pass the data for the long running task to the windows service from my web api project? How would my API project be notified when the task is complete? Would I have to do all this through statuses within a database and query it every so often?

Comment: @Selthien this is a perfect question to ask over at https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com. This site is for very specific code questions. The Software Engineering site is moe for broad how-do-I-architect-my-app type questions.

Comment: You sometimes see this as a number of API endpoints. You initiate the job and rather than returning "200 OK", you will return a "201 Created". That resposne may contain an ID or a URL (or both!) which you can use to enquire about the status of that job. The response from that endpoint might be "OK" with a message of "running" or "processing" and eventually "finished" or "errored". If you then need to return data a final endpoint might be called to obtain all the information. This means each call is fairly short, and you do not need to have long time-outs on the requesting service.